# Can a view selectively populate sections that appear outside the view in ASP.NET mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a simple site with bootstrap and .net core mvc (v3.0). Because most of the pages reuse the bootstrap container, I decided to put that in the layout file, so that I wouldn't be repeating the same setup everywhere.

This has the downside that if a view needs fixed elements, those end up getting fixed to the container, not the viewport.

I'm wondering if it's possible to call some sort of syntax inside the view.cshtml file that could cause a section to be rendered in the _Layout.cshtml file (sorry if this has been answered, but I wasn't sure what to search for).

For instance

_Layout.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment _environment
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
</head>
<body>
    @* this div only gets rendered based on logic inside the view*@
    <div id="conditionalViewDiv">

    </div>
    <div class="content container-fluid pl-0 pr-0 moveable" id="containerMain">
        <main role="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and then in SomeView.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@MadeUpRenderCommand("conditionalViewDiv")

@*other view stuff*@
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.0), **View components** are intended anywhere you have reusable rendering logic, similar to partial views, but they're much more powerful. The main difference is when you use partial view you still have dependency on controller while in View Component you don't need a controller. So there is a separation of concern.

> A view component is a C# class that provides a partial view
>   with the data that it needs, independently from the parent view and the action that renders it.

Good enlightening examples can be found, particularly:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-view-components-in-asp-net-core-mvc/
- https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html

Hope this helped.